# How to remove all punctuation in a string just get the words separated by spaces in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to remove any type of special characters in a string like this:

```
This is, ,,, *&% a ::; demo +  String.  +
Need to**@!/// format:::::
 !!! this.`
```

Output Required:

```
This is a demo String Need to format this
```

How to do this using REGEX?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check for any repeated instance of a non-number, non-letter character and repeat with a space:

```
# string(41) "This is a demo String Need to format this"
$str = trim( preg_replace( "/[^0-9a-z]+/i", " ", $str ) );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/hXu6skTc

```
/       # Denotes start of pattern
[       # Denotes start of character class
 ^      # Not, or negative
 0-9    # Numbers 0 through 9 (Or, "Not a number" because of ^
 a-z    # Letters a through z (Or, "Not a letter or number" because of ^0-9
]       # Denotes end of character class
+       # Matches 1 or more instances of the character class match
/       # Denotes end of pattern
i       # Case-insensitive, a-z also means A-Z
```

Comment: Wooo.. Thanks Man. It really works.. And also thanks for the quick tutorial. It really helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]#', '', $yourString);
```

If characters are not alphabet, numbers or space, it is replaced with empty string.

**Example:**

```
$yourString = 'This is, ,,, *&% a ::; demo +  String.  + Need to**@!/// format::::: !!! this.`';
$newStr = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]#', '', $yourString);
echo $newStr;
```

**Result:**

```
This is a demo String Need to format this
```

---

So you can allow more characters if you want by putting them in:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

---

**Note:** Also if you don't want to allow *multiple spaces between words* (though they wont be shown when output in browser), you need to use this instead:

```
preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+#', ' ', $yourString);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wants multiple whitespaces in the result string.

Comment: weel i am getting this output has he said "This is a demo String Need to format this"

Comment: No, the output has multiple whitespaces in it. Cannot paste the result  here since the browser will make it 1 space.

Comment: ya they are both same whats the differnece i cant see any ?? is there any i am getting same has the answer and u said

Comment: There is no point of multiple spaces between words, also they will turn to one anyway when output on browser.

Comment: @Rinzler The difference is the number of spaces between words. I edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: ooh but when i ran the code in my localhost it worked fine and and gave me the same output has i pasted i used this code "preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]#', '', $yourString);"

Comment: @Sarfraz You are assuming the OP is outputting this to a browser immediately and that they don't care about extra whitespace.  This could just as easily be heading to a database, or it could be output in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: ohh let me check through var_dump() i got this result // string(48) "This is a demo String Need to format this"

Comment: @rinzler The Only problem was the multiple spaces or no spaces. I solved it like this:

$patterns = array("#[^a-zA-Z0-9]#","/\s+/");
 $string   = trim(preg_replace( $patterns, " ", $string ));

Comment: @Rinzler: If you inspect the element via console, you will see it, however I have also updated answer if multiple spaces aren't needed.

Comment: ya i saw it in firebug now thanks if my opinion helped to improve an answer then am glad :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', ' ', $string);
```

You may also want to allow `'` in your character class to have conjunctions like `don't` not be turned into `don t`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z\']+/i', ' ', $string);
```

You might also want to trim it afterwards to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z\']+/i', ' ', $string));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', ' ', $str); 
// This is a demo String Need to format this
```

Comment: This works, but `$1` doesn't do anything so there is no point on including it.